# Cancel a live stream "fast motion" catch-up in Flash

Tags: flash, buffer, netstream

When streaming a live stream, if you hide the browser window/tab (e.g. by going to a different tab or minimizing the browser) - where the live stream is playing in
and then after awhile you go back to it - then everything that 'happened' in the stream since the window was hidden is played back in **fast motion** until it reaches to the "live point". 
How can I cancel this functionality? 
I'm assuming this relates to the 'smart seeking' functionality that the NetStream have, 
 however, even when I set the following:

```
ns.bufferTime = 0;
ns.bufferTimeMax = 0;
ns.backBufferTime = 0;
ns.inBufferSeek = false;
ns.maxPauseBufferTime = 0;
```

on the receiving side - this ***still*** happens. 
Any way of canceling it out completely?

**EDIT:**
Someone at Adobe's forum pointed out this for me:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#bufferTimeMax

It describes a "catch-up" feature that Flash Player have.
However, according to that information this feature should only operate if 
**bufferTimeMax** is set to > 0 - but, as mentioned, this still happens, even if I set 
*bufferTimeMax* to 0.
I also tried setting it (and all other properties mentioned above) to **-1**, but it didn't help either...

Comment: Yuval did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to solve the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied and pasted that from your code, you're missing a "." between ns and bufferTimeMax... so you're just setting an unused variable named nsbufferTimeMax to 0.